# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol SmsCbEtwsInfo among others

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telephony

I am working on an android app using the Telephony library built into the android SDK to test emergency alerts. I have a bunch of import statements.

Such as

```
import com.android.cellbroadcastservice.CbGeoUtils;
import com.android.cellbroadcastservice.GsmAlphabet;
import com.android.cellbroadcastservice.SmsCbHeader;
import com.android.cellbroadcastservice.SmsCbHeader.DataCodingScheme;
import com.android.internal.telephony.SmsConstants;
import android.telephony.CbGeoUtils.Circle;
import android.telephony.CbGeoUtils.Geometry;
import android.telephony.CbGeoUtils.LatLng;
import android.telephony.CbGeoUtils.Polygon;
import android.telephony.Rlog;
import android.telephony.SmsCbLocation;
import android.telephony.SmsCbMessage;
import static android.telephony.SmsCbEtwsInfo.ETWS_WARNING_TYPE_EARTHQUAKE;
import static android.telephony.SmsCbEtwsInfo.ETWS_WARNING_TYPE_EARTHQUAKE_AND_TSUNAMI;
import static android.telephony.SmsCbEtwsInfo.ETWS_WARNING_TYPE_OTHER_EMERGENCY;
import static android.telephony.SmsCbEtwsInfo.ETWS_WARNING_TYPE_TEST_MESSAGE;
import static android.telephony.SmsCbEtwsInfo.ETWS_WARNING_TYPE_TSUNAMI;
```

However, these all show up as red and say that they cannot find the symbol after the telephony import. Some modules do exist, such as

`import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager;`

which works without problem.

Building also gives me the error

```
error: cannot find symbol
import static android.telephony.SmsCbEtwsInfo.ETWS_WARNING_TYPE_EARTHQUAKE;
                               ^
  symbol:   class SmsCbEtwsInfo
  location: package android.telephony
```

So I am rather stuck. I went into my SDK folder and files such as SmsCbEtwsInfo.java were in the telephony folder, along with other modules I could access. So I have no idea why I can't seem to import these specific modules. I have tried researching for similar instances of this but to no avail

I also tried Invalidating and restarting the cache